# Code that reads file and keeps track of "friends"

Tags: python, list, file

I need some help!  I have a file that has a bunch of numbers in a list.  It looks something like this:

0 1

1 3

4 8

4 1

I need a way to see how many times the numbers are linked...

For example, 1 is linked to 3 and 4,

while 4 is linked to 1 and 8

Any tips?

**Code as of right now using Ajax1234's suggestion**

```
with open(file_name) as friends:
    network = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in friends]
    d = defaultdict(list)
    data = filter(lambda x:x, [list(re.findall('\d+', i)) for i in friends])                     
    for a,b in data:
        d[int(a)].append(int(b))

    print(dict(d))
```

It does not output anything.

When printing network:

```
['0 1', '0 2', '0 3', '1 4', '1 6', '1 7', '1 9', '2 3', '2 6', '2 8', '2 9', '3 8', '3 9', '4 6', '4 7', '4 8', '5 9', '6 8', '7 8']
```

Comment: Is this relation symmetric?  If 4 is linked to 1, does that mean that 1 is linked to 4?

Comment: Yes you are correct.  Think of the numbers as people.  So 1 will be friends with 4 it means that 4 will also be friends with 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
d = defaultdict(list)
s = """
  0 1
  1 3
  4 8
  4 1
 """
network = [list(map(int, re.findall('\d+', line.rstrip('\n')))) for line in friends][1:] #for removing the single first value.
for a, b in network:
    d[a].append(b)

print(dict(d))

new_friend_lists = {a:b+[i for i in d if a in d[i]] for a, b in d.items()}
for a, b in new_friend_lists.items():
    for i in b:
       if i not in d:
            d[i].extend([c for c, e in new_friend_lists.items() if i in e])
       d[a].append(i)

final_list = {a:list(set(b)) for a, b in d.items()}
```

When running the code above on the file data output you posted above, this is the output:

```
{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [0, 9, 4, 6, 7], 2: [0, 8, 3, 6, 9], 3: [0, 8, 2, 9], 4: [8, 1, 6, 7], 5: [9], 6: [8, 1, 2, 4], 7: [8, 1, 4], 8: [2, 3, 4, 6, 7], 9: [1, 2, 3, 5]}
```

Comment: @Vcoss if this answer assisted you, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I had to modify your code so that it reads from a file, however now it does not output anything.  I will edit my question so that you can see what I did. @Ajax1234

Comment: @Vcoss that is odd, could you post what output is returned when you print `network`? That is the root of the problem.

Comment: Sure!  Edited the main question with it now.

Comment: @Vcoss Thanks for the edit! Please see my answer for the changes.

Comment: Thank you, In the file, there is a single number at the start.  How would I ignore that in this code?

Comment: @Vcoss please see my recent edit, I added list slicing to remove the first value.

Comment: Great!  Thank you.  Final question, I swear :P.  How would I keep track of hows friend is whos.  You made it so that It is all listed beautifully but now how would I make it so that it has something like:
    0 is friends with 1,2,3 ... While 1 is friends with 1,2,3,0.  Like keeping track of who knows who.

Comment: @Vcoss that can be implemented however I am confused, as 1 is friends with `[4, 6, 7, 9]`, not `1,2,3,0`. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, see how 0 is friends with 1, that means 1 is friends with 0.  They go both ways.

Comment: @Vcoss I added a new solution that will relate all friends to each other. For instance, 0 has [1, 2, 3] as friends, thus, 1 would have [4, 6, 7, 9, 0] as total friends.

Comment: Im getting an error that says AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: How would I also have 8 and 9 in the dictionary?  so that 8 would have their friend block etc.